# Pre-2006 movie/series about a kidnapping with a character possibly named China

Tags: identify-this-movie, identify-this-tv-show

Pre-2006, color, originally watched on TV (could have been on a cable channel like Lifetime but not sure), think it's a movie, but could also be TV show, English, USA

**Stuff that I'm more sure of:**

A blonde? Long-haired child about 7-12 was kidnapped and the kidnapper is holding her and an adult woman, possibly brunette with medium length hair, and named China (or it could be the child's name) in a room with a dressing table and mirror.

The scene I remember is the two of them sitting in front of the dressing room table and the woman might have been brushing the child's hair. The woman is on the girl's side, not an accomplice

**Less Sure of:**

The male kidnapper's motivation was to raise the little girl like a doll? The girl is kept in a room and wears a nightdress/dress type outfit. And the adult woman might have been investigating or she might have been a casualty?

Genre: definitely not fantasy/sci-fi, comedy, etc.; psychological/drama/suspense?

Other details that may have be completely off:
the adult woman is surprised to find that the girl is still alive (which is the basis of the investigation detail); the man is in his 30-50s.
the child is calm;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like the 1997 miniseries [Intensity](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118350/combined) with John C. McGinley and Molly Parker.

> Chyna Shepherd is a twenty-six-year-old psychology student who survived an extremely troubled past. While visiting Laura Templeton's house, a farm in the Napa Valley, a serial killer named Edgler Foreman Vess breaks into the house, taking Laura and killing her parents. Chyna survives and manages to follow him. In doing so, she learns of Vess's captive: a young, innocent girl, Ariel, trapped in Vess's home far from the Napa Valley. Chyna feels a great sense of responsibility for this girl, and she travels deeper into her nightmare.

Ariel is in a catatonic state. It was based on a [Dean Koontz novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensity_(novel)) of the same name. Here's a clip: